# character vs character varying vs text in sequelize node js

Tags: node.js, types, sequelize.js

how will define data types for the character, character varying and text in sequelize,

**Code:**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var { sequelize } = require('../config/seqConfig');

var craMinDataEntry = sequelize.define('cra_minimum_data', {
  
    receipt: {
        // To define data type character
        type: Sequelize.STRING(17),
        allowNull: true,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
    user_name: {
        // To define data type character varying
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
    },
    source: {
        //To define data type text
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        allowNull: false,
    }
    , {
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: false,
    createdAt: false,
    updatedAt: false

});
```

Is my definition are correct or any modification is needed?

Answer (score 0):

*Short answer:* The datatypes you have look fine.

*Longer answer:* I would recommend trying to execute your code against a database while using [sequelize logging](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getting-started.html#logging), as well as [force syncing](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html#model-synchronization) the creation of the table.  This will produce a SQL `create table ...` statement, allowing you to check the data types that are being created in the database.  Just add `logging: console.log` to the options argument in the `Sequelize` constructor (see [sequelize logging](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getting-started.html#logging) for more information).

**Warning:**

Statements like

```
await craMinDataEntry.sync({ force: true });
```

will overwrite the corresponding table in your database, so you'll lose any existing data, unless you change the name to the table for testing purposes.  Consequently, this should really only be done in a development environment.  Change the model to something like:

```
var craMinDataEntry = sequelize.define('test_cra_minimum_data', {
    // ...
}, {
    // ...
    freezeTableName: true,
    // ... 
});
```

That will just create a test table in the database.